# Authenticating to SSL enabled website from terminal

Tags: php, bash, shell, curl, ssl

I have a SSL enable webpage mypage/login.html. This page as for a user and pass. I want to POST my UserId and Pass from a Terminal. I donno wheather its possible using TELNET.
I tried with cURL, read about it. But i din find any solution so far. Have head can write php script using curl to login. COuld any body help. Basically i want a script which will be run on user command on during system startup. main thing is to POST my user ID and pass from my Terminal to that webserver , so it Authenticates me and allows me further. Could someone help??

Comment: SSL is the least of the problem here, that'll work entirely transparently. What kind of authentication does the site use? Is it HTTP authentication? Is it a login form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the command line program `openssl` for that. It works just like telnet:

```
~$ openssl s_client -connect www.google.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, O = GeoTrust Inc., CN = GeoTrust Global CA
... secure connection details, certificates, etc ...
---
GET /
HTTP/1.0 302 Found
Location: https://www.google.nl/?gws_rd=cr&ei=CoLRUpfVG8a50QW59oG4CA
... rest of HTTP data / document ...
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that something like

```
curl -d userID=foo -d pass=bar https://10.0.0.1/letmein.php
```

should do what you want.

From the [curl(1) man page](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-d):

> **`-d`, `--data <data>`**
>
> (HTTP) Sends the specified data in a POST request to the HTTP server, in the same way that a browser does when a user has filled in an HTML form and presses the submit button.

If you need cURL to do URL-encoding for you, try [`--data-urlencode`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--data-urlencode) instead of `-d`.

Comment: I really appreciate your answers, In first case username and password is the name of the html variable which accepts my username and password?? openssl only creates a telnet session i think so.. does it allow to POST to the webserver??

Comment: Using CURL for ssl site is another issue.now as u said, this should log me in, but it does happen
curl -d username=(ur username) -d password=(ur password) http://warez-bb.org/login.php
It gives me the source code of the login page.
in case of ssl sites, it ask for certificate, i do provide cert, so it says the Subject name is different from Host name i do curl -u and post the uname n password. it gives the source code of login page